# Downloading a file using Services Views

Tags: views, services

I've created an API using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) Module (by way of the Services Views Module) that I am accessing via a Single Page Application. In this application, users need to be able to download a selection of files.

This selection of files has been setup in a view that make available to the app using the Services Views Module. When I access the api in my app, I can get all off my data fine but I run into an issue when I try and download movies and pdf's.

Is there a special formatter I need in order to make files downloadable via my api?